# Handlebars main.js console logging

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

How would I go about performing a console.log (or something similar) when using Handlebars.js? **I am not trying to console.log from inside the template file.**

```
/*jslint node: true, white: true, nomen: true, plusplus: true, sloppy: true*/

var fs = require("fs"),
    Handlebars = require("handlebars");

/**
 * Render the Handlebars template
 * @param   {object} resume
 * @returns {object}
 */
function render(resume) {

    var css = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/style.css", "utf-8"),
        template = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/resume.hbs", "utf-8");

    console.log(resume);

    return Handlebars.compile(template)({
        css: css,
        resume: resume
    });
}

module.exports = {
    render: render
};
```

Comment: This should work unless you have an error before your console log. What is your question about ? Aren't you getting your message or are you getting an error ? Explain a bit more.

Comment: You're right. This wasn't even the problem in the end... I'll post an answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was found while working on a [custom template](https://github.com/kneeki/jsonresume-theme-Dave) for [JSON Resume](https://jsonresume.org/).

When loading the template via `resume serve` the  control file `index.js` is loaded. Refreshing the page **does not** reload the `index.js` file. Simply `CTRL C` out of serving the resume and issue `resume serve` again to reload the `index.js` file.